# Pass variables with JQUERY MODAL PHP

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Dears,

I found solutions for bootstrap modals but I couldn't work because I don't know jquery and I'm working with another use-ready modal

http://jquerymodal.com/

```html
<div id="ex2" class="modal">
  <p><?php include('modal.php'); ?></p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>

<a href="#ex2" rel="modal:open"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots fa-2x"></i></a>
```

I'm working with these codes how can I send a variable to the modal (inside a modal I have a form and I need to send an id from original page)

Alternative;

add a variable to the link mysite.com/mypage.php?id=1
and in the modal.php I get the id and open modal automatically with page load if there is a id on the link (I can do the if part but how can I automatically open the model) class="model show" did not work

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.post() of jquery to send your variable value on load, and in 
modal.php you can receive it with :

```
if(isset($_POST["name_you_gived_on_Post"]))
{
$myvar = $_POST["name_you_gived_on_Post"];
}
```

Comment: I use hyperlink to open modal because the button is a font awesome icon, can I post and open the modal this way ? or how can I do, thank you so much for your answer

Comment: the only way I think that you can do to pass a variable in this case while opening a new page is to pass it with the url of the page while opening it , another thing you can use is the LocalStorage of your browser to save the value of your variable.

Comment: Hey TahaG did you found your answer ?

Comment: no I will try with ajax I will change variable when mouse on the icon (if it's possible) and when I click and open the modal I hope that variable will be available :)

Comment: why wouldn't you use:  $(document).on('click', '#idofsubmitbutton', function(){
    var Data = 'Your Input Data';
        window.open('model.php?data='+Data);
  }); , It's what you said in the beginning

Comment: if I try to open model with get value it doesn't work I don't know why